# how to expand the view width after loading ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, frame

how to expand the view width after loading ios?
I have a view that will be initialized with `self.view.bounds`
I want this view to have another frame after loading how can I do that?
FYI this view is a sub view of Scrollview.
So I am initializing a view, that is subview of a scroll view, inside a view.

Comment: How do you know what width it should be? What did you try so far? What went wrong? Show code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard and autolayout,

Update constants of width constrain of the view. You can create directly IBOutlet of the constraint and

```
int desiredWidth = 150;
_modifyViewWidthConstraint.constant       = desiredWidth;
```

If the views are created programatically, then simply change the frame

```
modifyView.frame = CGRectMake(modifyView.frame.origin.x, modifyView.frame.origin.y,desiredWidth,modifyView.frame.size.height);
```

Keeping all its x,y and height same as previous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto Layout on view and given width constant to view then change property of that constant,change relation from == to >= and change priority from 1000 to 250.Hope it will work you.